# Remove '-Any-' value from exposed filter term field

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a view with an exposed filter field. This field always shows the `-Any-` value. The data shown is dynamic so I cannot select the values to show. I have to remove that option in some way.

I've looked at [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/83678/drupal-7-views-exposed-filter-removing-any-and-sorting-items) answer but this is for a form and I'm trying to do this for a views page of type chart. Anyway, I can't even dpm the form name as is said in the example.

My view name is `x_report_plus_feature_dashboard` and the display is `page1`.

How can I do this? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I was able to remove the '-Any-' value with the following code:

```
function HOOK_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    unset ($form['field_MYFIELD_tid_selective']["#options"]['All']);
  }
}
```

But now I have a problem. When I go to the view, the data shown is still the same that was shown when `-Any-` was selected. For me it's ok to show the data for the first entry as default but how to do it?

Comment: The `dpm()` should work to figure out the form name. The views filters use the same Drupal forms API. There must be some issue with your custom module.

Comment: Thanks for the help, cleaver. How can I get the form_id? Or is the the one I wrote above?

Answer (score 1):

Setting the exposed filter to `required` will remove the `-Any-` option.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your answer. That exposed field was using [Views Selective Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_selective_filters) and that wouldn't work. Anyway, I changed it to normal expose and the Any doesn't show. The only issue is when I don't have any terms. It gives me the error: An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator.